# In need to display different colors in BAR -  chat by using silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

In silverlight generally we can create a chat but i need create a BAR-chat based on the below requirement.

Example:
         students marks  50,70,60,90.....like that having .for me based on marks i need to create different colors in the bar chat.below >50 means red color ,>70 means amber color ,>90 means green color...

I need different colors to display in the bar chat based on the marks...

Answer (score 0):

Using IValueConverter is an option for you.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Gray">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:NumberToBrushConverter x:Key="NumberToBrushConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListBox x:Name="List1">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NumberToBrushConverter}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

And code behind:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 };
List1.ItemsSource = numbers;
```

And the ValueConverter class:

```
public class NumberToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            switch ((int)value)
            {
                case 10: return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                case 20: return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                case 30: return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            }
        }

        return Colors.Transparent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```